# Connecting to Web Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, micropython

I'm trying to connect a bluetooth device (ESP32, peripheral) with Web Bluetooth (central). I send an addvertising packet and I can see the device on the web page, but I fail to connect to it. My code for the ESP32 looks like this: (MicroPython)

`ble.gap_advertise(interval_us=100, adv_data=bytearray(b'\x02\x01\x06\x06\x08\x45\x53\x50\x33\x32\x11\x07\x26\x6c\x34\x7f\xb2\x38\x61\x82\xbe\x4d\x1d\x64\xf1\xf7\x93\x16\x02\x19\x80'),resp_data=None, connectable=True)`

In Web Bluetooth (JavaScript) I just request a device and try to connect to the gatt.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript does work with another bluetooth peripheral. (RN4678)

And in JavaScript I can find the peripheral (ESP32) after filtering, but I can't connect to it.

JavaScirpt:

`server = await device.gatt.connect()`
The code stops at that point.

MicroPython:

The GATT is defined using:
`ble.gatts.register.services()` 
I'm trying to use my own service, not a SIG defined one. So I advertise b'(x...') which contains the flags, the service and the device name. And it works with the nRF Connect App. I can send and recive data. But it doesn't work with the bluetooth enabled web browser.

Thanks for your help!